# Should I compress the data being exposed via wcf service?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, compression

I'm creating a WCF service which exposes an object graph which is expected to grow in size while the service is up and running.  In playing with some test data (85k), smaller that would be expected when live, I hit the default 65k message size limit.  A quick look on the net showed that it was simple enough to extend this in the config.

As I'm creating the service and the client which consumes it, I wondered if there was added value in compressing the data before I sent it.  Having run a brief test, the test data shrunk to around 7k, so this looks like it will aid in the time for the message to be sent over the wire and increase the amount of data I could send.

The service pre-prepares the data before the first call is made and so there is no initial overhead on every call due to the compression.

Is it a good idea to do this for the sake of scalability, and trying to optimise performance, or is this adding complexity where it is not needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By reading your post, seems like you were able to implement this compression quite easily.

If you control both the sides, adding a layer of Compression/Decompression does not really increase complexity for general scenarios when you gain a lot of bandwidth benefit out of it.

What you could do to minimize the complexity by implementing some patterns like `Interceptor` or `Decorator`.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you're not using an obscure compression format, I don't think you're adding any appreciable complexity. One or two lines of code. Perhaps you could add a parameter to the service call which lets the client choose compressed or uncompressed data.

Answer (score 0):

Can you all be more specific, what all I should do to encrypt & compress and decrypt & decompress data successfully at both ends? Which compression Algo is the best for compressing large Data taking less time to compress and decompress and also compressing and decompressing small data, to efficiently transfer the data between client and server.

@decyclone: what is interceptor or decorator? Please be specific and clear.